# Are there any open-source 'skinnable' photography galleries?

Tags: open-source, photo-galleries

I am looking for a ready made gallery system that I can install on a subdomain of my site to allow people who I photograph the ability to enter a user name and password and download / order copies of their images.

Is there a industry standard?

It would be nice to theme it so it is in-keeping with my main site

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**[Piwigo](http://piwigo.org/)** is an open-source photo gallery you can install to a subdomain of your site. There are many themes and extensions, access control by password, and editable CSS if you really want to make heavy customisations. I use it on my site and I can definitely recommend it.

Comment: Im going to give Piwigo a try - I am hoping I can go on shoots and give people login details so they can only see their shots - maybe in the future offer the ability to order prints

Answer (score 5):

Your two main choices are [Gallery 2](http://gallery.menalto.com/) and [Zenphoto](http://www.zenphoto.org/). Both offer plugins that offer shopping cart functionality. Gallery has more sophisticated choices, but unfortunately, the Gallery developers have a habit of throwing everything out and starting again — Gallery 2 is a total rewrite of Gallery 1, and Gallery 3 is another total rewrite.

And, the latest version is stripped down to the point where it *doesn't* have very much of a plugin ecosystem. If you just want to theme it, that's pretty easy to do (especially if you've got some basic php skills), but anything sophisticated is likely to be more work than it's worth. Luckily, there still are a lot of people that 
are actively working on Gallery 2 plugins and so on, so it's not necessarily a dead-end choice.

Both Zenphoto and Gallery (in either version) should be easy to integrate nicely into your main site.

Answer (score 5):

Another option is the open photo project: http://theopenphotoproject.org/ which is worth a look.

Comment: This seems to be in the process of changing its name to 'Trovebox', but that might just be the name of the hosted version (similar to wordpress.org vs wordpress.com I guess).

Comment: It looks like the link is pointing to something else now

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Trovebox. It's a hosted service but you can use your own subdomain.

https://trovebox.com/feature/whitelabel

In addition to being 'skinnable' you can share using password protected albums or even create groups with signins.

Answer (score 0):

If your looking for a static gallery generator one of the best is [jAlbum](http://jalbum.net) It will take an album of photos allow you to edit the order, captions, etc. then publish a theme-able gallery that you can then post to a web server. It is a free for personal use and offers paid as you go services for added features, cloud storage, and extra widgets like comments and other extras.

For the Linux side (and those who don't like jAlbum) You can use [digiKam](http://www.digikam.org/) which has an export to HTML feature which will also let you make your own themes.

Comment: Re-reading the original post. It is clear the poster was not looking for a static gallery generator. And so this answer is incorrect but could be useful for others.

Comment: Also, free-for-personal-use isn't open source.

Comment: But digiKam is open source. :D